# how to get the print of section of .aspx page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am printing reports as tables in `.aspx page`

Now i want to print that section containing table. how can i print that section only?

As I got `javascript` function to print the `whole page` with `window.print()` but I want only some section to get printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a print stylesheet to hide elements you don't want printed:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" media="print" />
```

(This article on A List Apart has some useful info on print stylesheets: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/)